# drop down logon in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have these dropdown forms and I am looking for a way to slide them back up whenever i click on anywhere outside of the forms.
My javascript code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('#login-trigger').click(
function(){
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();        

    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#signup-trigger').click(
function(){
    $(this).next('#signup-content').slideToggle();

    })    
});
```

My main reason for needing this function is so the two forms wouldnt be open at the same time or with any other dropdown list I add later

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a basic event handler on the document itself:

```
$(document).click(function(){
        $('#login-content').slideUp();
        $('#signup-trigger').slideUp();       
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks, although this just prevent it from sliding up in the first place as it is included in the click function

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, quick and easy. Just add a class of `.sliding-content` to your sliding elements, then add this:

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.sliding-content)', function() {
   $('.sliding-content').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This sounded a nice way, would figure out this way and post my result later. was away for a while

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it this way, thanks to both answer submitters for the guide

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('#login-trigger').click(
function(e){
    $('#signup-content').slideUp();
    $('#categories').slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $('#login-content').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
    }
)
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#signup-trigger').click(
function(e){
    $('#login-content').slideUp();
    $('#categories').slideUp();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).next('#signup-content').slideToggle();
    $('#signup-content').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
    })    
});
```

Mainly I used the e.stopPropagation function to prevent the drop down button itself from sliding back
up its own slide down form. and then added the document click function to slide up all forms that are slided down

```
$(document).click(function(){function(){
$('#login-content').slideUp();
$('#signup-content').slideUp();
$('#categories').slideUp();

});
```